# How to design mobile views for outlook web addin

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

**Problem:**

I have a Outlook Web-Addin approved for Desktop. However they have recommended certain style changes for iOS and Android to be approved by them. My code is all plain HTML / Javascript and very simple. What basic framework can I use to simply get the styling right?

**Background:**

My Application was built using plain Jquery + plain Javascript and CSS I also had used Fabric UI Fabric JS for Desktop which just allowed me to use different components like Spinner etc with some additional javascript/CSS

**Office UI Fabric? Fabric React? Fabric Core? framework7? :**

I am confused what exactly to use for my usecase.
Office UI Fabric : I believe its outdated / Deprecated and hence Microsoft won't support it. 
At one place they have also mentioned you can use framework7 and their website also talks about Fabric React and Fabric Core.
When I check Fabric Core: It seems its only CSS and Colors and Typography.

**Question**

Seems Microsoft wnats a Card layout kind of UI for iOs and Android. What exactly should I be using? I do not know react enough and not sure its really worth that effort.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-mobile-addins

Notably the following sections:

What's different on mobile?
• The small size and quick interactions make designing for mobile a challenge. To ensure quality experiences for our customers, we are setting strict validation criteria that must be met by an add-in declaring mobile support, in order to be approved in AppSource.
o The add-in MUST adhere to the UI guidelines.
o The scenario for the add-in MUST make sense on mobile.

Make it feel as native as possible

This does mean that your add-in will have to visually be different when it runs in Outlook on iOS versus Android. We recommend taking a look at Framework7 as one option to help you with styling. we are not asking to use any particular library but whatever you are using, it should follow UI guidelines.